# 'env -i' -- doesn't remove all env vars from subshell

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

I thought that `env -i` runs a command with a blank environment, but the following code (in a bash v4.4 function) works -- as in, COMMAND is executed with only env vars from ENVFILE.

So, why are the explicitly-set env vars ENVFILE and COMMAND not removed by `env -i`?

```
export local ENVFILE="$1" COMMAND="$2"

/usr/bin/env -i /bin/bash -c ". ${ENVFILE}; ${COMMAND}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because they're substituted in the *current* shell, not the invoked one.

```
export local ENVFILE="$1" COMMAND="$2"

/usr/bin/env -i /bin/bash -c '. ${ENVFILE}; ${COMMAND}'
```